# Java PreparedStatement set interval

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

What is the correct escaping of the **interval** in sql statement?

Currently I have the following code which escapes the **customerId** variable:

```
final String query = "delete from login_history where time < current_timestamp - '" + days + " days'::interval and customer_id = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, customerId);
int deleted = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

But I also want to escape **days**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `"+ days +"` with a `?`, change the `setInt` to have 2 instead of 1 and add

```
preparedStatement.setWhateverTypeDaysIs(1, days);
```

Comment: Thanks. `time < current_timestamp - '? days'::interval` works perfectly!

Comment: You're a wizard!

Comment: `START_TS + '? minutes'::interval > systimestamp`/`START_TS + '? minute'::interval > systimestamp` doesn't work for me: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Comment: @EduardGrigoryev Write the query and get it working in a SQL client and then take that query into java and replace the parameters one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to pass an int parameter multiplied by a fixed interval E.g.

```
select * from foo where (time + ? * INTERVAL '1' DAY) > current_timestamp
```

You can put days, hours whatever...
and than `setInt` parameter

Comment: The only solution that works for munites: `(START_TS + ? * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) > systimestamp`! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?::interval` in your SQL text and use setString() like

```
setString(1, "30 minutes")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, "java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 3"